# If a station simultaneously maintains three TCP connections,can use the same TCP port for the three connections?

Tags: tcp

If a station simultaneously maintains three TCP connections,can use the same TCP port  for the three connections? If yes how it could distinguish packets?

Answer (score 1):

Each connection is made of the below parameters.

(source ip,source port destination ip, destination port, protocol).

Thus, the station can distinguish packets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, multiple connections to the same IP and port are possible.  They're distinguished by the IP and port on the *other* end of each connection.